# print using regular expression for every line I have

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a text with 3589 lines,
every 5 lines I want to extract the image name from it, using Regular expression.

The line looks like: URL,https://google.com/Document/Projects/Images/Turk/IMG-2021-606-WA1227.jpg

I need to only print the image name, which is: "IMG-2021-606-WA1227.jpg"

Code I have so far:

```
file1 = open('./data/input/filesn.csv', 'r')
Lines = file1.readlines()
count = 0
for line in Lines:
    print("Line{}: {}".format(count, line.strip()))
    count += 1
    if "URL" in line :
        print("Image:")
```

- how can I print the image name after print("Image:")

Comment: Did you try splitting the string by `/` and taking the last element? Easier and less error-prone than using regex.

Comment: I did, but didn't know how to get the very last element after the "/". I did ``` print("Image:', pattern.split(line)[0])``` but it is printing the whole line and not the last one. any help?

Comment: you could do `print("Image:", line.split('/')[-1])`. I'd recommend reading more about indexing in python. Here's a reference: https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_access_list_items.asp

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to compile a pattern if you need to use it multiple times, add `pattern = re.compile('IMG.*?\.jpg')` before the loop, then inside the print statement, print the substring that matches the pattern:

```py
print("Image:", pattern.findall(line)[0])
```

Understanding the pattern `'IMG.*?\.jpg'`:

- The pattern will look for `IMG` text in the line
- If it is found, `.*?\.jpg` will take all the strings upto the point
  where first occurrence of `.jpg` is found.
- If `.jpg` is not found after finding `IMG` or `IMG` is not found, it means line doesn't match the given regex.

If you get the IndexError, that means `line` does not contain the required substring that matches the pattern, so it'd be better if you store the variable locally and print the first item only if it is non-empty:

```py
img = pattern.findall(line)
if img:
    print(img[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am getting "IndexError: list indix out of range"

Comment: That is because the line does not have the required substring which matches the pattern, you can store the result from pattern to a local variable `img =  pattern.findall(line)`, and print `img[0]` if `img` is not empty. See the updated answer

Comment: how can we add any line that ends with .jpg or .JPG?